# Can schema version be different from jars file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jar, xsd

My lib folder has spring jars of the 4.0.4 release. In the `applicationContext.xml` I use the 3.0 version of the schema.

For exemple:
I have the following jars:

- spring-beans-4.0.4
- spring-context-4.0.4
- spring-core-4.0.4
- spring-expression-4.0.4
- sprig-web-4.0.4
- spring-webmvc-4.0.4

and in the applicationContext.xml I wrote:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

My questions are:

Is it possible have different versions between schema and jar?

If yes, what are the consequences?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sometime it throws an error. So try to use same version of jars and in xml use generalised schema not version based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this type of schema in xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">
```

don't use : `context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` and like this because when application get bigger to handle all this thing very cumbersome.

and if possible use `maven` instead of `jars`, just define version once in a `property` then use that only in pom import of `dependency`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't used maven because I have to respect some specifics.

Comment: okay then fine, I am just telling you. So if you are not using maven then keep versioning of jar in mind. Good luck.